# how to use user api in strongloop and cloudant on ibm bluemix

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ibm-cloud, strongloop, cloudant

i made this sample app in ibm bluemix.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/library/mo-build-a-hybrid-app-strongloop-bluemix-trs/index.html

i want to add user signup, login, profile ( edit user info ) function for this sample app.

but i have errors.

if you can, please tell me how to use strongloop User api & clouadnt in right way.

best,

Comment: Could you try to be more specific? Did you try something? Did it work? What went wrong?

Comment: What are the errors that you are encountering? That information will help in diagnosing the problem.